# Replace Div With Simple Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to be able to replace my div within each other but it s not working cant figure out why

```
$(function(){
    $('#4').replaceWith ('#2');
});
```

here is a the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cybersix/aeyg89rd/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just a typo

change

```
<div class='short yellow id="4"'>
```

with

```
<div class='short yellow' id="4">
```

As @kao3991 already saw

> [**replaceWith**](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method needs an object in parameter, not a selector

so you have to change

```
$(function(){
        $('#4').replaceWith ('#2');
    });
```

with

```
$(function(){
    $('#4').replaceWith ($('#2'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62brm6o5/1/

Comment: thanks but the css and the content hasnt moved with it how do i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

jquery `replaceWith` method needs an object in parameter, not a selector. So `$('#2').replaceWith($('#4'));` will work. 
And you've made a typo as InvernoMuto mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work fine, you forget the  close the class of div 4...